# Altium issue - routing a trace does not dim other nets

Tags: altium

I have an issue with Altium (Version 2023, perpetual), that when I route a trace with the "Interactive Route Connection" feature, other components are not dimmed and so it is hard to see where to route:

[image]

The funny thing is, that it works for differential routing. I tried to reset the view already, but without success. Any ideas, what that could be?

Comment: there's a preferences setting that controls this behavior, probably in the interactive routing section

Comment: Have you tried asking on the many Altium support sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **View Configuration** panel, under the **View Options** tab, look for **Mask and Dim Settings**.

[image: Mask and Dim Settings in Altium]

The **Dimmed Objects** slider affects the brightness of dimmed objects. The leftmost position will make them invisible while the rightmost position applies no dimming at all. It may be that you have this too far right to see a distinction.

You can do this while routing by starting the route, pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd> and adjusting the slider until it suits your preference. To resume routing, look for the pause symbol in the middle of the editor and click it.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was already playing with that, but never while routing